# How to create Traffic Mirroring of a Load Balancer for a Window of Time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, load-balancing, pipeline, amazon-elb

I have a pipeline where the front end is a load balancer, taking in a json payload. I want to set up a traffic mirror of the json payload on a one time basis for a window of 4-6 hours. The current pipeline is completely on AWS. The final goal is to load this windowed payload into an S3 bucket for E2E testing purposes.

Does anyone know a method for traffic mirroring during a one time window?

I'm quite new to this field, so any resources you can point me to would be great.

Comment: What does traffic mirroring mean exactly?

Comment: Specifically AWS Application Load Balancer receives HTTP POSTS, the traffic being the series of POSTS. Traffic Mirroring is essentially "duplicating" or mirroring traffic from one network lane to another as I understand it. More can be read here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/traffic-mirroring-how-it-works.html

Comment: You would need to make API calls (or use the console) when you wish to activate and deactivate the traffic mirroring. I don't think there is any command to tell it when to start & stop.